# Is "by..." an adverbial phrase?

Tags: adverbials

Adverbial phrases are known to answer questions related to how, when or where something was done.

Is this considered as an adverbial phrase?

**By pressing the button**, she opened the door and left the room.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a preposition phrase, since it has the preposition "by" as head. You could call it an adverbial, but **adjunct** is a better term. It functions here as a modifier in clause structure, more specifically one of means.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason that the term 'adjunct' is preferred to 'adverbial' is two-fold: (1) It is very unsatisfactory to have a function term that is morphologically derived from a category term. (2) 'Adverbial phrase' is quite often used for any phrase functioning as adverbial and hence likely to be confused with adverb phrase, i.e. one headed by an adverb.

Comment: @BillJ, You ratify it in three ways a) It's a prepositional phrase, b) It's also an adverbial, and c) 'Adjunct' is a better term. Isn't it that a 'morphologically derived one' is a standard/ common yardstick which is interpreted based on its function?

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly an adverbial, explaining the condition fulfilled that enabled 'her' to *open the door [and hence leave the room]*. It modifies the whole matrix sentence (arguably only the first clause, with the compound predicate being better rephrased).

Some might classify this as an adverbial (nowadays an adverbial *clause*) of manner, though it really should be classed as facilitation / means (explaining how the opening was *achieved*, not just how it happened):

> After seeing the expression of manner by means of adverbs [adverbials]
> [eg *Tamara sings like a professional*], let's move to deal with the
> expression of means and instrument. **Means** is expressed by a phrase
> [or clause] introduced by **by**:
>
> - *Tom Cruise always travels by plane.*
> - *Beckham managed to sell the house by advertising it in a newspaper.*
>
> (On the other hand, *instrument* is introduced by a phrase
> introduced by *with* [or a clause introduced by *using*]:
>
> - Victoria hit Ana with her bag.)

[[Oposinet: The expression of manner, means and instrument](https://www.oposinet.com/temario-de-ingles-secundaria/temario-4-ingles-secundaria/topic-15-the-expression-of-manner-means-and-instrument/); modified]